# Am I wrong to think that MERGE is superior to UPDATE SET (-, -, -) = SELECT -, -, -?

Tags: oracle, merge, correlated-subquery

I've been refining some MERGE techniques and the syntax seems so much better than UPDATE/SELECT that I can't imaging using UPDATE/SELECT at all any more.

Am I crazy?  What are the downsides to using MERGE as the only correlated update mechanism?

Comment: This is a great question! If you don't get a good answer here I'd suggest reposting it on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

No You are not crazy.Not at All.
Its better than update/insert. That's why oracle introduced it at the first place.

Its simpler,easier to write, far less messy, and updates/inserts  in sets hence performance effective.